# 500 Internal Service Request error with Ajax Post, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

In javascript I have the following:

```
var jobData = {
           "SquareN": rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat,
               "SquareE": rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng,
               "SquareS": rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat,
               "SquareW": rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng,
               "SiteName": $("#jobname").val(),
               "SiteType": 3,
               "EstFlags": $("#numberFlags").val()
          };
    $.ajax({
        url: "send_jobsite.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {jobSite: jobData},

    });
```

Then in my php file I am doing $_POST['jobSite'] but am getting a 500 Internal Service Error from the POST. I am not sure what the cause of the error is or how to fix it. This is my first attempt at doing an ajax post to send data to a php server script, which will then take that data and send it to a mysql database.

Any tips would be great.

Php:

```
if($con->connect_errno) {
  printf("Connect Failed: %s\n", $con->connect_error);
  exit();
}

echo $_POST['jobSite'];

$con->close();

?>
```

The first line before what I posted is a connection to the database, which is correct, so didn't include.

Comment: can you post your php script ?

Comment: There may be some errors in the file send_jobsite.php, that is why u got internal server error.

Comment: As is always the case with server-side errors; **check the error log**

Comment: What error log in chrome debugging tools? It is just giving me the 500 internal service error.

Comment: Your HTTP server error log, the thing executing `send_jobsite.php`

Comment: Also, your `data` format seems odd.  As it is, `$_POST['jobSite']` will be an array. Is that what you expect it to be?

Comment: Possibly? As long as I can access the data from the $_POST['jobsSite']. How do I look at the http server error log?

Comment: is your URL param correct? This expects `send_jobsite.php` file to be on the same level as the JS file making the ajax request.

Comment: Yes it is, it appears that  my query to send the data to the database is causing the issue.

Comment: @TylerDahle how are you running the PHP script? Via Apache (or similar; XAMPP, WAMP, MAMP, etc), NGINX or the built-in PHP server? All should have easily found error logs

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be to do with your `data` format. When you send something like this (as you are)

```
data: {foo: {
    a: "a",
    b: "b"
}}
```

jQuery will encode the data as

```
foo%5Ba%5D=a&foo%5Bb%5D=b
```

or decoded

```
foo[a]=a&foo[b]=b
```

which can be read by PHP as an associative array, ie

```
$foo_a = $_POST['foo']['a'];
$foo_b = $_POST['foo']['b'];
```

---

Chances are, you are not accessing the `$_POST` data correctly. You should be using something like

```
$_POST['jobSite']['SquareN']
```

etc. Alternatively, change your JavaScript code to

```
data: jobData,
```

and access the properties via

```
$_POST['SquareN']
```

and so on.

Comment: so I have the jobData as a JSON object, then did data: jobData, then in my php I'm doing $_POST['SquareN'] but am still getting internal service error. I think it is definitely my database query to add the info to the database. I'm not really sure the correct syntax for the database query I suppose

Comment: @TylerDahle [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like your requested jobData is not correct format.I am guessing you are trying to send JSON data. Please try something like below data.

var jobData = '{"SquareN": "ff","SquareE": "dd","SquareS": "aa","SquareW": "bb","SiteName": "ll","SiteType": 3,"EstFlags": "nn"}';

And also check at send_jobsite.php file what input data you are receiving.

Comment: OP definitely appears to be wanting to access the data as typical `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` via `$_POST` so I don't think using a manually created JSON string is the right answer

Comment: Changed the jobData to your suggestion just to try, and didn't get an error. But attempting to do a query to my database to insert the data into a table causes error 500, so I must not be doing that right.